# Additional UART on Raspberry Pi2

Tags: uart, raspberry-pi2, gpio, serial-communication

There is one UART (UART0: GPIO 14 and 15) on raspberry pi 2 board for serial communication.

I wondered, in the case that only GPIOs must be used & not USB ports, if it is possible to customize/program other GPIOs to be used as additional UARTs.

If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: You are confused: you do not use GPIOs as UARTs (unless you're bit-banging).  A UART is an actual peripheral device that occupies silicon on the chip.  It's a functional block distinct from the GPIOs on the SoC.  It's connected to the CPU by some bus, and is also connected to the board by pins multiplexed with GPIOs.  The typical method of connecting more peripherals devices such as a UART chip would be through the SoC's *external bus* (if it has one).   Note that USB is also a bus.

Comment: There are USB ports on the board, but because of our application requirement we dot use them. Referring to Raspberry Pi2 pinout I could not find anything indicating that any pins used as SoC's external bus. Would it be possible to use an external UART adapter chip and connect its output to some GPIOs (other than those connected to UART component on board) and get serial data from them?

Comment: The SoC external bus is routed to the external memory (e.g. DRAM, flash, external peripheral chips) and typically not available on a board header.  I don't understand *"external UART adapter chip"* (too many adjectives).  You're rather sloppy with terminology.   The *"output"*  (?) of a UART would probably be its external interface, and connecting its RxD and TxD to GPIOs makes no sense.  The UART internal interface should be connected to a bus, not GPIOs.  Look at a UART chip datasheet; you would need at least 11 pins/lines.

Comment: Maybe a proper interface from _SPI_ or _I2C_ to a simple _UART_ chip will be a good solution. Bit bang protocols are not fast, but for some applications it may be enough. The driver will be another issue.

Answer (score 0):

No problem! There are many bit-banging solutions out there for having multiple virtual/software UARTs. Just google for them, but it is probably better to use the [PIGPIO](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/) libraries. [Here](https://github.com/themrleon/RpiSoft-UART) and [here](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/tree/master/uart01) are two other examples.

Here's an example Python script (using the PIGPIO library).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import time
import difflib
import pigpio

RX=18

try:
        pi = pigpio.pi()
        pi.set_mode(RX, pigpio.INPUT)
        pi.bb_serial_read_open(RX, 9600, 8)

        print "DATA - SOFTWARE SERIAL:"
        while 1:
                (count, data) = pi.bb_serial_read(RX)
                if count:
                        print data
                time.sleep(1)

except:
        pi.bb_serial_read_close(RX)
        pi.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO bit-banging on Raspberry Pi is dark and full of terrors. You can use USB Serial Devices but they absolutely must be FTDI based if you are on Windows IoT Core. (Linux based, I'm sure you don't have this restriction)

The single UART on Raspberry Pi is really lacking. My solution has been to use Arduino Nano to control my sensor - one sensor per Nano. The Raspberry Pi communicates with each Nano through USB-Serial communications via a USB mini cable.

Something else you can possibly use is a CP2102 USB to TTL/Serial Module. Connect that to your external device and then connect the CP2102 to a USB port on the Pi. I haven't tried this yet, but expect to in the next week or so.

Here are a couple FTDI USB-Serial devices I have found.

[USB to 6 Wire Header](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06ZYPLFNB)

[USB to DB9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QG83YVC)